# How to download and parse JSON with Python FAST

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, performance, download

I am trying to download JSON file with

```
with urlopen(url_str) as url:
    return json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

and it works unacceptable slow (10+ times slower than equivalent Java code).

Is there any way to perform this operation at normal speed?

**UPDATE**

I wrote this way:

```
def read_json_data(url_str: str):
    req = Request(url_str, headers={'Accept-encoding': 'gzip'})
    with urlopen(req) as resp:
        if resp.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
            with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=resp) as fp:
                data = json.load(fp)
        else:
            data = json.load(resp)
        return data
```

But getting error on `json.load(fp)`:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Why? Isn't `json.load` (without `s`) accept file pointer?

Comment: could you provide the link that you are downloading? Also what is the approximate size? Finally, if speed is important, I wouldn't consider using python in the first place.

Comment: It was because of usage of gzip compression which Java code was supporting and python didn't

Comment: the `requests` module supports gzip.

Answer (score 1):

`urlopen` supports `gzip`, you just have to ask for it:

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
import json

urlstr = "http://example.com/your-json-url"

req = urllib.request.Request(urlstr,
    headers={'Accept-encoding':'gzip'})

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
if resp.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    print("got gzip")
    data = json.load(gzip.GzipFile(resp))
else:
    print("no gzip")
    data = json.load(resp)
```

Comment: for me `gzip.GzipFile()` doesn't accept `resp`, saying `TypeError: invalid file: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00000192A6343DA0>`